# Login system for multiple platforms (android, website, ios)

Tags: php, authentication

Is the following secure and is the following a good way of working?

I am making a login system for multiple platforms.(website, android, ios)
When you register successfully, the server generates a random 'access key'.
Then I send that key back to the client.
The client stores the key locally.
This way the client only has to log in once.
With that key the client can do anything (sending messages, receiving messages, etc)

For all clearness each user has a different 'access_key'

Comment: what if i get ahold of one of these keys while you sending it to the client?

Comment: What if the user gets a new device? How will they re-generate the 'access key?' In my opinion, that's much more complicated than just using a background service to authenticate logins. There are plenty of platforms already available such as Parse, etc.

Comment: I would be using https

Comment: You mean, after login (not register) they will be provided with the key?

Comment: yes! That is what I mean

Comment: SSL would be a good start.

Comment: this is basically the same as setting a cookie on login. It can be intercepted and sent to the server by someone else trying to hack. So you'll want to do something like store the user-agent and IP on the server (i.e. in the session) when you log the user in, and check on subsequent calls that it hasn't changed (because if it has, probably someone intercepted the cookie and is trying to get access that way) so deny them access.

Comment: So, it is some kind of like a REST call. That depends on your application flow. You can make the access key long enough and short lived. And of course over SSL. And for web app I think you should take a different approach.

Comment: But a cookie can't be intercepted when using ssl.. right?

Comment: But if there is a better way of staying logged. Please tell me!

Comment: `But a cookie can't be intercepted when using ssl.. right?` Theoretically it shouldn't, but I've seen something like that happen by confusion on the webserver's part. You can get a session criss-cross if you aren't validating something like ip/browser pair along with the session id.

Comment: For mobile, validating IP along with access token could cause frequent log outs as the phone switches between wifi and cellular data